# Angular Material 2 - Display mat-tab-label text in two lines (like title an subtitle)

Tags: angular-material, mat-tab

I'd like to display text in mat-tab-label like some title and its subtitle. For example as on [mat-card-header](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) where the title and subtitle can be set and displayed one under the other.

Is it possible to make text in mat-label be displayed like in this screenshot?
[image]

Here is the [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-with-2-line-label?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that I tried, but nothing works - all the tags always display inline.

Comment: Please describe the appearance you would like to achieve as some may not have access to linked images.

Comment: The nearest thing is an appearance of [mat-card-header](https://material.angular.io/components/card/examples) where title and subtitle can be setted. I want to do same for mat-tab-label (title and subtitle)

Comment: Revise your original post - be specific such as 'title above subtitle' - don't just refer to something you know about but others may not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing with just HTML, Angular Material formats them using `inline-flex` and puts them on one line. You need to use the `::ng-deep` combinator to change the style of the components inside the shadow tree. [Here's](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459) a little article to read about, google for more.

And [here is your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-with-2-line-label-x1dpjp) with the answer. Of yourse, add your classes to it and adjust the stylesheet so you are not manipulating all of the tabs, unless that's what you want to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. [My stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-with-2-line-label?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) fixed too.

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Angular Material (tested on 9.2.0), you can use `ng-template mat-tab-label` and plain HTML to add a new line:

```html
<mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        38<br />
        description
    </ng-template>
    Content inside the tab
</mat-tab>
```

And if you need to style the tabs, you can simply use the CSS classes:

```scss
.mat-tab-labels {
    .mat-tab-label {
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        background-color: #bebdbd;
        &.mat-tab-label-active {
            background-color: #27817a;
        }
    }
}
```